# Problem with downloading from npm

Tags: node.js

I recently got a pi and I am tinkering with getting a webserver on it. Using a tutorial I found I figured I'd do this with node.js and express, a library for node.js.

I tried to install express using npm, but had no luck. In the screenshot you can see that I had registry.npmjs.org in /etc/hosts pointing to 151.101.16.162, which threw ENETUNREACH as error. I found this IP address using some google searches, by the way.

I then removed the address from the hosts file. This is how it originally was. This threw the EAI_AGAIN error.

I guess this has to do with me not assigning the right IP address to the URL. So my question is, does anyone know the right IP address, or what I am actually doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome, Gut feel is that you do not have internet access.  Can you ping 8.8.8.8 and ping google.com and post the results here please as part of the question (just use edit)?  One minor point, It's normally better to use copy / paste for screens as it makes it easier to read and copy bits out from :)

Comment: Seemed to be a problem with the internet connection indeed. Changed a few things in /etc/dhcpcd.conf and restarted the service, now everything's working fine.

I'll remember that tip about pasting the terminal output for next time :)